# How to schedule a MS Teams meeting programmatically?

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create an application that allows the user to schedule MS Teams Meeting. I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-create-and-enable-an-event-as-an-online-meeting. I am getting the email but not the joining link. I tried different ways but I am stuck at this for a day now. Any help is appreciated.

Sample Request:

```
{
    "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "HTML",
      "content": "Does noon work for you?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "location":{
        "displayName":"Harry's Bar"
    },
    "attendees": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address":"samanthab@contoso.com",
          "name": "Samantha Booth"
        },
        "type": "required"
      }
    ],
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "isOnlineMeeting": true,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
  }
```

Expected response (with Teams join link)

```
{
    "@odata.etag":"W/\"ZlnW4RIAV06KYYwlrfNZvQAALfZeRQ==\"",
    "id":"AAMkAGI1AAAt8AHjAAA=",
    "createdDateTime":"2017-04-15T03:00:50.7579581Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime":"2017-04-15T03:00:51.245372Z",
    "categories":[
    ],
    "originalStartTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time",
    "originalEndTimeZone":"Pacific Standard Time", 
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart":15,
    "isReminderOn":true,
    "hasAttachments":false,
    "hideAttendees": false,
    "subject":"Let's go brunch",
    "bodyPreview":"Does noon work for you?",
    "importance":"normal",
    "sensitivity":"normal",
    "isAllDay":false,
    "isCancelled":false,
    "isDraft": false,
    "isOrganizer":true,
    "responseRequested":true,
    "seriesMasterId":null,
    "showAs":"busy",
    "type":"singleInstance",
    "onlineMeetingUrl":null,
    "isOnlineMeeting": true,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness",
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "responseStatus":{
        "response":"organizer",
        "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body":{
        "contentType":"html",
        "content":"<html><head></head><body>Does late morning work for you?</body></html>"
    },
    "start":{
        "dateTime":"2017-04-15T11:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end":{
        "dateTime":"2017-04-15T12:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone":"Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Harry's Bar",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueId": "Harry's Bar",
        "uniqueIdType": "private"
    },
    "locations": [
        {
            "displayName": "Harry's Bar",
            "locationType": "default",
            "uniqueIdType": "unknown"
        }
    ],
    "recurrence":null,
    "attendees":[
        {
            "type":"required",
            "status":{
                "response":"none",
                "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress":{
                "name":"Samantha Booth",
                "address":"samanthab@contoso.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "organizer":{
        "emailAddress":{
            "name":"Dana Swope",
            "address":"danas@contoso.com"
        }
    },
    "onlineMeeting": {
        "joinUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_NzIyNzhlMGEtM2YyZC00ZmY0LTlhNzUtZmZjNWFmZGNlNzE2%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22bc55b173-cff6-457d-b7a1-64bda7d7581a%22%7d",
        "conferenceId": "177513992",
        "tollNumber": "+1 425 555 0123"
    }
}
```

Actual Response:

```
{
    "categories": [],
    "transactionId": null,
    "originalStartTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
    "bodyPreview": "Does noon work for you?",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "isOnlineMeeting": false,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "occurrenceId": null,
    "isDraft": false,
    "hideAttendees": false,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body>Does noon work for you?</body></html>"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T14:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Harry's Bar",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueId": "Harry's Bar",
        "uniqueIdType": "private"
    },
    "locations": [
        {
            "displayName": "Harry's Bar",
            "locationType": "default",
            "uniqueId": "Harry's Bar",
            "uniqueIdType": "private"
        }
    ],
    "recurrence": null,
    "attendees": [
        {
            "type": "required",
            "status": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Attendee"
            }
        }
    ],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
        }
    },
    "onlineMeeting": null
}
```

Whatever I do,, the `onlineMeeting` is always null.

Comment: I know this comes from the example on the page you linked, but for interest why are you setting the "location" as well as "isOnlineMeeting"? Maybe try with "location" set to null, if it makes a difference?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow, I just tried to follow the example. I did try setting the location to null and `isOnlineMeeting` to true, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs if teams for business meeting provider that is **Online Teams Meeting** is not enabled for the user in Outlook.

Check if the user is enabled for **`teamsForBusiness`** like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar
```

[image]

```json
"allowedOnlineMeetingProviders": [
"teamsForBusiness"
],
"defaultOnlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
```

If the ***user is not enabled with Teams for Business***, then the response will be like below:

```json
"allowedOnlineMeetingProviders": [],  
"defaultOnlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
```

Hence **to resolve the error**, make sure that Teams for Business meeting provider is enabled for the user.

***I am able to create the online meeting with `onlineMeeting` join URL:***

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events

{
"subject": "Let's go for lunch",
"body": {
"contentType": "HTML",
"content": "Does noon work for you?"
},
"start": {
"dateTime": "2024-03-25T12:00:00",
"timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"end": {
"dateTime": "2024-03-25T14:00:00",
"timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
},
"location": {
"displayName": "Harry's Bar"
},
"attendees": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "xxx@contoso.com",
"name": "Name"
},
"type": "required"
}
],
"allowNewTimeProposals": true,
"isOnlineMeeting": true,
"onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft Teams URL is missed when creating a event by Graph API - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/815263/microsoft-teams-url-is-missed-when-creating-a-even) by JanardhanaVedham-MSFT

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I am getting the following response when I hit https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar

 {  "name": "Calendar",
    "color": "auto",
    "hexColor": "",
    "isDefaultCalendar": true,
    "changeKey": "KbmXZ+YUG0WPiiM8ZjwwLgAAAAADnA==",
    "canShare": true,
    "canViewPrivateItems": true,
    "canEdit": true,
    "allowedOnlineMeetingProviders": [
        "skypeForConsumer"
    ],
    "defaultOnlineMeetingProvider": "skypeForConsumer",
    "isTallyingResponses": true,
    "isRemovable": false,
}

Is there anything I can do fix this?

Comment: Yes it is allowed for skypeForConsumer not teamsForBusiness hence you are facing the issue

Comment: Open a support case with Outlook Calendar team from your tenant for dedicated support and escalating it to Microsoft engineering team to analyze this issue and further assistance. You can raise the case either from Azure or M365 admin center of your tenant.

Comment: @Rukmini if you don't mind, can you guide me on the same? Like I have an active azure personal subscription but I am not exactly sure on how to raise a support case

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request

Comment: OR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide